# How to implement theme options in Laravel Website?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, laravel, themes

I want to implement theme options module in my website which is obviously powered by Laravel. I'm wondering where to store options like: Social icons address, Google map code for contact page, Copyright text.. Like we have in WordPress. What is the best practice ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. Most common thing I see is a database that keeps some data stored so you can create, update, delete and read this data. The admin environment like the Wordpress admin you can create as you want. You of course have to set-up the front-end and back-end. To make the final product you have all this little products you have to make so actually this question is too global.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the settings you can store in the project configuration. See:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration
And later you can use `config('app.name')` for example to get app name in all parts of your code-base.

Some of the settings you can store in your DB, with your own-created settings-mechanism (if settings are updated frequently from WEB-interface, admin-part for example).